# hash tables and time complexity in c

Tags: c

I am pretty new the hashtable implementation in c and I was looking over some interview questions and I found one about finding the odd occurrences of elements in an array.  I have everything setup and working as:

```
int a[256]={0};
char *str="hhlloworldd";
int i;

for(i=0;i<strlen(str);++i)
    a[str[i]]++;

for(i=0;i<strlen(str);i++)
{
    if(a[str[i]]%2 == 1)
    {
        printf("Odd occurrence of %c\n",str[i]);
    }
}
```

The majority of hashtable solutions I've seen (as far as counting elements in an array or string etc) are using 2 for loops. 1 to insert whatever it may be and 1 to check the results afterwards. I believe this is still O(n) complexity because (correct me if I am wrong) but its passing n times through the string twice as O(n) + O(n) which equates to O(n).  My question is is there a way to check the hashtable as you are inserting into it to eliminate the second for loop?

Comment: This is a simple array - calling it a hash table is a bit of a stretch.

Comment: 1) I'd call it a histogram. 2) I'd use unsigned types for the counts 2) I'd not call strlen() repeatedly 3) I'd use size_t for the length 4) Often, char is signed, negative indexing in the array would certainly make things go *very* wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two observations about your code:

- It has nothing to do with [hash tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), because there is no collision resolution.
- The complexity of the code is indeed `O(n)`, but your analysis is incorrect: the timing of the second loop is `O(256)`, which is another way of saying `O(1)`, for the overall complexity of `O(n)`.

Answer (score 1):

Many comments:

- A hash table can have no collisions. For example a hash table with perfect hashing is still a hash table. Hash table definitions focus on the mapping from key to value by means of a hash function (and that's it for the definition). See, for example (for an identical lookup array):

http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?HashTable

So the above is a hash table with a perfect hash function (which maps all elements with no collision) that maps some element (a character) to a value (number of occurrences).

- As already commented, strlen is Θ(n), so calling it every loop iteration results in Θ(n²). Pulling strlen out of the loop solves this.
- The second loop is Θ(n), but as already commented too, it makes more sense if this loop were Θ(e) in general (grows with the number of elements), Θ(1) in this case. Anyway, check the original problem for what it really is asking for.
- It's not possible to merge both loops. The reason for this is because all the array elements can only be accounted for after processing the last element in the string. To understand this. If that were not true, then there would be some earlier moment that we can conclude that some hash value were ready. Then just consider the moment before we process the last element. If we havent processed the last element, then we need to increment by 1 one of them. Then any of the 256 buckets could  have changed. But there's no way to guess which one, we need to read the last element. After the end of the loop the only way out is to loop again.

Answer (score 0):

your code seems to have a bug - but maybe I didn't get your requirements correctly:

If some character x appears an odd number of times in the input, the second for-loop will report it as an "odd occurance" every time it is seen.

you should merge the two for-loops into one.
as a side note, putting an O(n) operation like strlen() in your loop condition relies on the compiler understanding str is not being modified so that strlen is not called repeatedly or you end up with quadratic performance.

```
int a[256]={0};
int n = strlen(str);
int i;

for(i=0;i<n;++i)
{
    ++a[str[i]];
    if(0 != a[str[i]]%2)
    {
        printf("Odd occurrence of %c\n",str[i]);
    }
}
```

Not sure why you would want a hash table in case the key space is small enough (in this case of size 256) for a trivial look-up table to work.

Comment: well so far you've confused me into thinking I've found a bug that wasn't there. Odds are we have different ideas of what the problem actually is, rather than a bug. Maybe a reading comprehension problem on my part or yours

Comment: just try this input on your code : `aaaaaa` (note: you can do all this in your head).

Comment: Prints 'Odd occurrence of a' 3 times and terminates, which is what I expected it to do.

Comment: it does have a bug though, it would crash on "negative" chars. I completely missed that one.